# MAUI toolkit Popup does not appear

Tags: c#, maui, maui-community-toolkit

I'm creating MAUI application for android (Net 7) and I want to use toolkit popup page for activityindicator. I done all like in documentation sample (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/popup) but when I put some code after this.ShowPopup or this.ShowPopupAsync popup is only displayed after this code is processed. What can I do about it?

I expect that popup will appear before processing the code.

pageBusy code:

```
Using CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views;
namespace eWMSDraft1.Pages;
public partial class pageBusy : Popup
{
    public pageBusy()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

pageBusy xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<toolkit:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
               xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             x:Class="eWMSDraft1.Pages.pageBusy">
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center">
            <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="True" />
        </StackLayout>
</toolkit:Popup>
```

pageLogin code:

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var popup = new pageBusy();
    this.ShowPopup(popup);
    
    Login();
}

public void Login()
{
.......
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code ? It will be easier to find the problem.

Comment: I think it's a problem of threading. When you call ShowPopup the popup is running on a different thread. So during the call of ShowPopup Login function is called too on the main thread.

Comment: An other way to make this is not use a popup. You could make a ViewModel with your login function and a property like IsRunning. When you enter in the login function put IsRunning to true and at the end of the function put him to false. That use binding. Put the indicator in an other view. And in the call of the view, set the binding on the IsVisible property.

Answer (score 1):

Like Quentin Guillaume said, it's a problem of threading. However, you can do this to achieve it:

popup xaml:

```xml
<toolkit:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.popup"
             Color="Transparent">
    
        <Frame WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="200"  CornerRadius="20" >
            <StackLayout Margin="10">
                <Label Text="You want to login?" FontSize="Title"/>
                <HorizontalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="End" Margin="0,70,0,0">
                    <Button Text="Yes"
                            Clicked="OnYesButtonClicked" Margin="10,0"/>
                    <Button Text="No"
                            Clicked="OnNoButtonClicked" />
                </HorizontalStackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
    
</toolkit:Popup>
```

popup xaml.cs:

```
public partial class popup : Popup
{
    public popup()
    {
        InitializeComponent();    
    }
    private void OnYesButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) => Close(true);

    private void OnNoButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)=>Close(false);
}
```

pageLogin code:

```
        private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await DisplayPopup();
        }

       public async Task DisplayPopup()
        {
           var popup = new popup();
           var result = await this.ShowPopupAsync(popup);

           if (result is bool boolResult)
            {
                if (boolResult)
                {
                    Login();
                }
                else
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

       public void Login()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("login");
        }
```

Only if you click the "Yes" button, it can login. And this is the [effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvYrg.jpg). Wish it's another workaround for you.

Comment: You can also add ActivityIndicator  to Frame like [this](https://imgur.com/a/SZ1N3r4) :)